# Unable to add values of dropdown fields

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an average of the values of a number of dropdown fields to generate the customer rating for a customer survey. I built this survey using ProcessMaker but I can't seem to get the javacript code to work. The script only executes the last else statement and displays "No Rating Available"

Below is the script;

```
var A = getField("Service_Delivery").value;
var B = getField("OnTime_Delivery").value;
var C = getField("Feedback").value;
var D = getField("Resolution").value;
var E = getField("Repeat_Findings").value;
var F = getField("Attitude").value;
//var SumTotal = A + B + C + D + E + F;
//var RatingVal = SumTotal/6;
var RatingVal;
var Result = getField("Result").value;
Result = RatingVal;
for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
A.onchange = function() { 
  RatingVal = (A + B + C + D + E + F )/6;
  Result.value = RatingVal;
};
B.onchange = function() {
  RatingVal = (A+ B+ C + D+ E + F)/6;
  Result = RatingVal;
};
C.onchange = function() {
  RatingVal = (A + B + C + D + E + F)/6;
  Result = RatingVal;
};
D.onchange = function() {
  RatingVal = (A + B + C + D + E + F)/6;
  Result = RatingVal;
};
E.onchange = function() {
  RatingVal = (A + B + C + D + E + F)/6;
  Result = RatingVal;
};
F.onchange = function() {
  RatingVal = (A + B + C + D + E + F)/6;
  Result = RatingVal;
};
}
//Result = changeValue("Result", RatingVal);
if (getField("Result").value==1) {
    getField("Rating").value= "Service Not Rendered";
    var show1= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show1);}
else if (getField("Result").value==2) {
  getField("Rating").value="Unsatisfactory";
  var show2= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show2);}
else if (getField("Result").value==3){
  getField("Rating").value="Satisfactory";
  var show3= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show3);}
else if (getField("Result").value==4){
  getField("Rating").value="Very Good";
var show4= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show4);}
else if (getField("Result").value==5){
  getField("Rating").value="Excellent";
var show5= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show5);}
else{
  getField("Rating").value="No Rating Available";
var show6= getField("Rating").value;
    alert(show6);}
```

Please assist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update your code to make it work. You can refer the following code:

```
var RatingVal;
for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
  getField("Service_Delivery").onchange = function() {  
  getval();  
  };
  getField("OnTime_Delivery").onchange = function() {
 getval();     
  };
  getField("Feedback").onchange = function() {
  getval();    
  };
  getField("Resolution").onchange = function() {
  getval();    
  };
  getField("Repeat_Findings").onchange = function() {
 getval();     
  };
  getField("Attitude").onchange = function() {  
   getval();   
  };
}

function getval(){
var A = parseInt(getField("Service_Delivery").value);
var B = parseInt(getField("OnTime_Delivery").value);
var C = parseInt(getField("Feedback").value);
var D = parseInt(getField("Resolution").value);
var E = parseInt(getField("Repeat_Findings").value);
var F = parseInt(getField("Attitude").value);
  var r = (A + B + C + D + E + F)/6;   
  RatingVal = parseInt(r);
  }

function displayResult(){
  changeValue("Result", RatingVal);
if (getField("Result").value==1) {     
  getField("Rating").value= "Service Not Rendered";     
  var show1= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show1);
}
else if (getField("Result").value==2) {   
  getField("Rating").value="Unsatisfactory";   
  var show2= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show2);
}
else if (getField("Result").value==3){   
  getField("Rating").value="Satisfactory";   
  var show3= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show3);
}
else if (getField("Result").value==4){   
  getField("Rating").value="Very Good";
  var show4= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show4);
}
else if (getField("Result").value==5){   
  getField("Rating").value="Excellent";
  var show5= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show5);
}
else{   
  getField("Rating").value="No Rating Available";
  var show6= getField("Rating").value;     
  alert(show6);
}
  }
getField("display").onclick = displayResult;
```

I have corrected the various issues in your code due to which the code was not working.

- When using onchange: it has to be used on an object and not the value
- As you are running your code when the Dynaform loads, it takes up the values of variables then and there and never gets the updated values on change. Thus, you need to call the function which gets the values of the variable every time you need to calculate RatingVal.
- The values we get from variables using the function getField("").value;
  is a string and to perform calculations on it, they need to be parsed to strings.
- I have used a button on click to finally display the value of Result and the corresponding value of Rating.

Please check the code if it works for you.

Hope this helps